# Why can't I run my React Native project?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I can't see how I'm getting these errors in my project.

I'm trying to run the `index.ios.js` (the one that comes with React Native when you make a project for the 1st time, the welcome screen) file in my simulator but it isn't letting me. I've posted a picture of one of the errors below.

The other `error` it's throwing at me is when I hit `Run`.

I'll also include the `package.json` and `.eslint` file: file below if that helps.

[image: ESLint Error]

`error` :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.43.3",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

`.eslint` file:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need to let ESLint know you're using ES2015 imports.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How would I do that?  I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Always read the plaque: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: @evolutionxbox uh, this is a very vague answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment asking you to read the ESLint documentation where it tells you how to remove the error. Specifically `ecmaFeatures`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ah I see.  I've included my `.eslint` file in my original post.  I got it from the website you linked me.  The ESLint error is now gone but I still can't run my project.

Comment: @klobbaks do you have a `.bablerc` file setup? You might also want to include `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0"` in your `package.json` under `devDependencies`. The `.babelrc` should contain `{
"presets": ["react-native"]
}`

Comment: @G0dsquad whenever I do put that under devDependencies, I'm getting a `cannot resolve symbol` error whenever I hover over my components which means my project will definitely not run.

Answer (score 0):

- Error when running `index.ios.js`: seems you are using **Node.js** Run configuration to start your application, but Node.js doesn't support ES6 modules natively (thus the Syntax error on import), and, of course, it doesn't support react-native cli options, so running node `index.ios.js` as you do won't start your app in ios emulator. You should have used **React Native** run configuration instead. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/, **Running and debugging the app** section
- ESLint: what does you ESLint configuration (`Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint`) look like? did you choose global or local ESLint?